# Convergence of infinite union on probability space

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,F,P)$ be a probability space. Let $B_n$ be a sequence of sets in $\Omega$. I'm trying to prove that $P((\cup_{n=1}^\infty b_n)\cap(\cup_{n=1}^k b_n)^C)\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. I have tried a number of set theory manipulations but got nowhere. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You probably mean convergence to $0$ instead of $\infty$. Do you know about "continuity of a measure from above"? This says that if $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ for all $n$ and $A = \bigcap A_n$, then $P(A_n) \to P(A)$.

Comment: Opps, fixed it. Let me look into that.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A_k:=(\cup_{n=1}^\infty b_n)\cap(\cup_{n=1}^k b_n)^C$ and notice that

- $A_{k+1}\subset A_k$ for each $k$;
- $\bigcap_k A_k=(\cup_{n=1}^\infty b_n)\cap(\cup_{n=1}^\infty b_n)^C =\emptyset$.

We thus have by continuity of a measure from above, as suggested by  PhoemueX, that $\mathbb P(A_n)\to 0$.